# Geofencing didEnterRegion not calling stored CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to use didEnterRegion to schedule notifications and didExitRegion to cancel notifications based on data stored in the CoreData file. It doesn't seem to be able to access the CoreData. I want to schedule the notifications based on a persons location.

How can I work around this?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    
    let ident = region.identifier
    scheduleLocationNotification(ident: ident)
    
}

func scheduleLocationNotification(ident: String) {
    let count = reminderArray.count
    print("Started Scheduled Geo")
    
    for i in 0...count {
        
        let reminder = reminderArray?[i]
        let id = reminder?.identity
        
        let date = reminderArray?[i].time ?? Date()
        var time: String = ""

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        formatter.dateStyle = .none
        
        if reminderArray?[i].time != nil {
            time = formatter.string(from: date)
        }

        if reminder?.active == true {
            if id == ident {
                scheduler.weekDaySchedule(time: time)
                print("GeoScheduled Notifications")
            }
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
   
    let ident = region.identifier
    cancelLocationNotification(ident: ident)
    
}

func cancelLocationNotification(ident: String) {

    let count = reminderArray.count
    print("Started Cancel Geo")
    
    for i in 0...count {
        
        let reminder = reminderArray?[i]
        let id = reminder?.identity
                    
        if reminder?.active == true {
            if id == ident {
                for i in 1...7 {
                    scheduler.cancelNotifications(identity: id! + String(i))
                    print("GeoCanceled Notifications")
                }
            }
          }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Where does region.identifier come from?

Comment: From the region targeted to watch, whether the user enters or exits the region.

Comment: What part of this uses Core Data, and what details lead you to suspect access problems?

Comment: @TomHarrington  reminderArray  is the access point to the Core Data.

Comment: It would help if you described how you initialize this array, if you have reason to think the problem is related to Core Data. Otherwise it's impossible to say. The array might be empty or nil, but there are lots of reasons that can happen.